# Number of $m$-tuples of $k$-subsets of $\{1,2,\cdots,\ n\}$ with overlaps

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $S=\{1,2,\cdots,\ n\}$ and let us consider the collection $\mathcal{A}$ of all $k$-subsets of $S$, where a $k$-subset is nothing but a subset of length $k$, $1\le k\le n$. Let us consider all possible unordered $m$ tuples of distinct elements from $\mathcal{A}$. Clearly, there will be $$N=\displaystyle \binom{\binom{n}{k}}{m}$$ such tuples. Now let me consider all the possible $m$-tuples where there is overlap between the coordinates of the tuple, i.e., let me consider all possible tuples $(C_1,\cdots,\ C_m)$ where $C_i\in \mathcal{A},\ C_i\ne C_j$ whever $i\ne j$ and $\exists$ at least one pair $i,j,\ i\ne j$ such that $C_i\cap C_j\ne \emptyset$. It is not difficult to show that the number of such tuples is $$N-\frac{n!}{m!(k!)^m(n-mk)!}$$ assuming $km\le n$. But what about the number of $m$-tuples when we consider a particular amount of overlap? What I mean to ask is the following:

> How can we find the number of $m$-tuples of elements of $\mathcal{A}$ when we consider a total overlap of $l<km$?

Let me give an example to elucidate what I mean by "total" overlap:

Let us take $n=8,m=4,l=5$. Then one tuple that satisfies my requirement is the following: $$\{\{1,3,6\},\{3,6,8\},\{1,7,8\},\{4,6,7\}\}$$ with the overlaps at $1,3,6,7,8$.

It will be best to give relevant hints/ideas rather than a full solution, if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, an "overlap" is just an $i\in S$ that is in more than one of the $k$-tuples?

Comment: Exactly @ThomasAndrews. There will be $l$ "total overlaps" if there are $l$ numbers from $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ which appear at more than one coordinates among the $m$ tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What follows is  a modest contribution with a  caveat on computational
complexity which I present here because *the complexity is better than
a total enumeration routine.*

The  key observation  is  that  we can  use  the Polya  Enumeration
Theorem (PET) to  implement a two-step process where  we first use PET
and the unlabeled set  operator $\mathfrak{P}_{=k}$ to compute the OGF
of the  $k$-subsets (very simple), with the  subsets being represented
by products of variables $A_1$  to $A_n.$ At this point the complexity
is  as bad  as total  enumeration.  We  then apply  PET a  second time
$\mathfrak{P}_{=m}$  and   this  is  where  we   win  because  similar
distributions of  variables collapse into s  single term. Summarizing,
the trick here is to use the species

$$\mathfrak{P}_{=m}(\mathfrak{P}_{=k}
(\mathcal{Q}_1+\cdots+\mathcal{Q}_n)).$$

We then iterate over all terms in this generating function and compute
the overlap which yields the  generating function of all $m$-tuples of
$k$-subsets   of  $[1,n]$  classified   according  to   overlap.  (The
contribution from a term retains the coefficient on the term.)

The cycle index  is computed from the recurrence  by Lovasz for the
set operator $\mathfrak{P}_{=n}$ on $n$ slots, which is

$$Z(P_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=1}^n (-1)^{l-1} a_l Z(P_{n-l})
\quad\text{where}\quad
Z(P_0) = 1.$$

With this set-up we can  compute distributions that are utterly out
of reach for  total enumeration (the variable $u$  represents the size
of the overlap).

We have for $n=10, k=5$ and $m=4$
$$48825\,{u}^{10}+3909150\,{u}^{9}+34290900\,{u}^{8}\\+73256400\,
{u}^{7}+45041850\,{u}^{6}+7282800\,{u}^{5}+229950\,{u}^{4}.$$

We have for $n=12, k=5$ and $m=3$
$$498960\,{u}^{7}+9110640\,{u}^{6}+32072040\,{u}^{5}\\+31711680\,
{u}^{4}+8630160\,{u}^{3}+462000\,{u}^{2}.$$

Finally we have for $n=11, k=6$ and $m=4$
$$7224525\,{u}^{11}+144611775\,{u}^{10}+607864950\,{u}^{9}+
768690615\,{u}^{8}\\+309978900\,{u}^{7}+34580700\,{u}^{6}+
757680\,{u}^{5}.$$

Observe that for $n=8, k=4$ and $m=4$ we obtain
$$1855\,{u}^{8}+84840\,{u}^{7}+394240\,{u}^{6}\\+367640\,{u}^{5}+
66360\,{u}^{4}+1960\,{u}^{3}$$

which is  a configuration that  is within reach of  total enumeration,
which  confirms the  correctness of  this result  on execution  of the
code.

The  Maple   code  including  the total  enumeration   routine  for
verification purposes was as follows.

```
with(combinat);

pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

pet_cycleind_set :=
proc(n)
local p, s;
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add((-1)^(l-1)*a[l]*
                   pet_cycleind_set(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

W :=
proc(n, k, m)
    option remember;
    local res, iter, src;

    src := choose([seq(p, p=1..n)], k);
    res := 0;

    iter :=
    proc(sofar, pos)
        local all, overlaps;

        if nops(sofar) = m then
            all :=
            [seq(seq(sofar[p][q], q=1..k), p=1..m)];

            overlaps :=
            nops(select(ent->ent[2] > 1,
                        convert(all, `multiset`)));
            res := res + u^overlaps;

            return;
        fi;

        if pos <= nops(src) then
            iter(sofar, pos+1);
            iter([op(sofar), src[pos]], pos+1);
        fi;
    end;

    iter([], 1);

    res;
end;


V :=
proc(n, k, m)
    option remember;
    local src, subsets, tuples, term, var, gf,
    overlap, deg;

    src := add(Q[p], p=1..n);

    subsets :=
    pet_varinto_cind(src, pet_cycleind_set(k));

    tuples :=
    expand(pet_varinto_cind(subsets, pet_cycleind_set(m)));

    if not type(tuples, `+`) then
        tuples := [tuples];
    fi;

    gf := 0;
    for term in tuples do
        overlap := 0;

        for var to n do
            deg := degree(term, Q[var]);

            if deg > 1 then
                overlap := overlap + 1;
            fi;

            term := term/Q[var]^deg;
        od;

        gf := gf + term*u^overlap;
    od;

    gf;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. though I did not understand this fully, I think this can be a legitimate way to solve the problem. I wil try to understand this better.